# MS Access 2010 Change Theme Through VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, themes

I was hoping to make a simple form in a MS Access 2010 database where the user can select a theme to be used. How do you change the database's theme through vba? Google hasn't been very helpful with this question.

Comment: I don't know a way to do this. A workaround would be to have some global variables that store background color, fore color, etc. Set these on selection of 'Theme' through a form. Then, on every form's onload event, set the properties (back color, fore, etc) to those values. You could have a sub that does this. Also, if necessary, iterate through the form's controls and set those as well ('For each control in form.controls') I'm not sure if there's an easy way to just set the theme, but if you wanted to devote about an hour, you could code your own.

Comment: I'm not sure that it would be worth it. I just converted from Access 2003 to 2010, and was doing an overhaul of the database, so I decided to update the visuals as well. I thought that while I was at it, I might as well take advantage of the themes since 2010 has them, but apparently its not as easy as it should be. Oh well, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question was asked a while ago, but since I came across it while I was researching setting up themes, I thought I should try to provide some of what I found.

When it comes to letting the user pick a theme, I think the easiest way is just to put the "Colors" button in your ribbon. If you happen to have made your own custom ribbon you can use `<control idMso="ThemeColorsGallery" />` to reference the "Colors" option.

If you want to try to have more exact control of what happens, I think I may have found an option, but it is a little more involved and I haven't worked out the details yet. I wanted to post it, though, because I thought someone might want to make use of it.

While working on controlling the image gallery feature, I realized that there is an entry for "Office Theme" in the hidden "MSysResources" table. I believe that whatever is in the "Office Theme" row in the "MySysResources" table determines what theme is loaded when your program starts. The way I tested this idea is that I picked a theme and then went to the table and saved the attachment to the desktop. I then went and picked a different theme and ensured that it was in place by looking at some of my forms. Then, I went back to the table and deleted what was in the "Office Theme" row and uploaded the saved file back into the attachment. After I closed and re-opened the program, the theme that I had saved to my desktop and then later re-loaded over the top of the current theme was the theme that was being used.

The way I envision this could possibly be used is that you could assign that attachment via code. In particular this seems as though it could be useful, if you wanted to override the default settings based on a configuration option specific to your program.

**Update 8/18/15:**
Someone has requested the extra details about how I was able to set my theme via VBA and so I'll provide them here. The basic theory is that I save the data from the attachment field in MSysResources to a table. Then if I ever need to overwrite the current theme with my saved theme, I extract it from my table and save it in the appropriate MSysResources record. Note that I'm using MySQL as my table storage platform and I'm using a MediumBlob field called "Lgo" to store the data.

Here are the two functions, I use. The first function saves the theme to my MySQL table. The second function extracts the saved data and saves it over the top of the current theme that is in the MSysResourcestable. Please note that to see the effect of the second function you will have to close and re-open your  program after having run the function.

```
Function SveThm()'Save Theme
    Dim MSR As Recordset, Atc As Recordset, LR As Recordset
    Set MSR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MSysResources WHERE [Name]='Office Theme'", dbOpenDynaset)
    If MSR.RecordCount > 0 Then
        Set Atc = MSR!Data.Value
        Set LR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbllgo;", dbOpenDynaset)
        If LR.RecordCount = 0 Then LR.AddNew Else LR.Edit
        LR!Stn = LgoStn
        LR!Lgo = CStr(Atc!FileData)
        LR!Typ = Typ
        LR.Update
        LR.Close
        MsgBox "Your theme has been saved."
    End If
End Function

Function SetMSys()'Set MSysResources
    Dim MSys As Recordset, Lgo As Recordset, Atc As Recordset
    Set MSys = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MSysResources WHERE [Name]='Office Theme'", dbOpenDynaset)
    If MSys.RecordCount > 0 Then
        MSys.Edit
        Set Atc = MSys!Data.Value
        Atc.Edit
        Set Lgo = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Lgo FROM tbllgo;", dbOpenDynaset)
        If Lgo.RecordCount > 0 Then Atc!FileData = Lgo!Lgo
        Lgo.Close
        Atc.Update
        MSys.Update
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I have since successfully implemented this for my system. If someone is interested in the details of how I did it, let me know.